# Traversing a tree - How to print the edges first

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

If I have a tree as below:

```
          A                Root Level
        /   \
       /     \
      G       Z            Level 1
     / \     /  \
    /   \   /    \
   C     D  T     J        Level 2
```

I have three questions:

- How can I traverse this tree such that Level 1 nodes are printed first, then root level, and then level 2

  G, Z, A, C, D, T, J
- How can I traverse this tree such that Level 1 nodes are printed first, then level 2, and then root level

  G, Z, C, D, T, J, A
- How can I traverse this tree such that Level 2 nodes are printed first, then level 1, and then root level

  C, D, T, J, G, Z, A

I'm going through tree traverals on wikipedia and remembered an old question I was once asked in an interview. I believe the question was either of the above three (most likely first or second).

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: You may be interested in this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are four levels?

Answer (score 0):

Preorder traversal: visit root before the subtrees

```
void preorder( BTREE__NODE_p_t node )
    if ( node != NULL )
        visit( node )
        preorder( node->left )
        preorder( node->right )
```

Inorder traversal: visit root between visiting the subtrees

```
void inorder( BTREE__NODE_p_t node )
    if ( node != NULL )
        inorder( node->left )
        visit( node )
        inorder( node->right )
```

Postorder traversal: visit root after visiting the subtrees

```
void postorder( BTREE__NODE_p_t node )
    if ( node != NULL )
        postorder( node->left )
        postorder( node->right )
        visit( node )
```

just to be clear, do want the algorithm to be generic, something like applying to n levels or just 3, cause the difference is like huge in terms of logic.